# Production environment is using staging database rather than production database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, passenger

I have 4 Rails environments.

- test
- development
- staging
- production

Rails are deployed perfectly to staging and production except the fact that production Rails is using staging database instead of production database. What am I doing wrong? What haven't I checked yet? Is there something in Capistrano where database setup is needed?

Here are some things to note.

**My `config/database.yml` clearly differentiates staging and production databases.**

```
staging:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: some_app
  pool: 5
  username: some_user
  password: some_pass
  host: staging.zzzzz.com
  port: 1911

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: some_app
  pool: 5
  username: some_user
  password: some_pass
  host: production.zzzzz.com
  port: 1611
```

**Rails environment for production and staging are identical.** In other words, `config/environments/staging.rb` and `config/environments/staging.rb` are identical.

**Passenger server in production environment should be running the Rails app in production environment.** See the line `RailsEnv production`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

LoadModule passenger_module /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.12/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.12/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11
PassengerRuby /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.12/bin/ruby
PassengerMaxPoolSize 20

Include conf/rhapcom.conf
Include conf/maintenance.conf
Include conf/redirects.conf

DocumentRoot /var/rails80/current/public
<Directory /var/rails80/current/public>
    RailsEnv production
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>

Include conf/oldrotw.conf
```

---

After some investigation, I found that production app is actually running in integration environment. I checked this through `Rails.env`. How do I specify to the production app that it should be running in `production` environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RackEnv production` to specify production environment.

---

Also, I can't help but notice this in your `config/database.yml`:

```
staging:
  # ...
  database: some_app
  # ...

production:
  # ...
  database: some_app
  # ...
```

Both staging and production environments are configured to use the same database.

> *Rails is using staging database instead of production database.*

No, they're both sharing a common database.

I believe you want to do something like this:

```
staging:
  # ...
  database: some_app_staging
  # ...

production:
  # ...
  database: some_app_production
  # ...
```

Now there are two distinct databases, each used in their appropriate environment.

Comment: Where should this line go to?

Comment: Note that in database.yml, the database host is already different. Changing the database name won't really fix this.

Comment: Missed that. Are those hosts separate machines?

Comment: Yeah pretty much. Different VMs. Databases are also hosted on different machines.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. There were some other configuration files I wasn't using in the passenger.conf that was messing it up.

Comment: That'll do it. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: In my case, I actually needed to add the line `passenger_app_env staging` on the project's staging VM inside the nginx's configuration. That fixed it.